# How to create customer with subscription using stripe in pabbly?

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

I have create curl request for create customer with subscription in pabbly

```
curl --location 'https://payments.pabbly.com/api/v1/subscription' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YTY2Njc4ZGYzOGYzMDllY2I5************************************' \
--header 'Cookie: SameSite=None' \
--data-raw '{
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "smith",
    "email": "jhonsmith@xxxxx.com",
    "card_number": "4111111111111111",
    "month": "11",
    "year": "2020",
    "cvv": "423",
    "gateway_type": "Stripe",
    "gateway_id": "6503********",
    "street": "arera colony",
    "city": "Bhopal",
    "state": "MP",
    "zip_code": "462016",
    "country": "IN",
    "plan_id": "5e***************",
    "redirect_to": "https://www.pabbly.com/",
    "plan_amount": "10",
    "quantity": "1"
}'
```

I have created plan with stripe payment gateway and used in above curl request

But i have got error like below

```
 "status": "failed",
    "message": "\"Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis.\"",
```

If i pass "gateway_type": 'test' then it's work.

If i remove card detail from above request with Stripe gateway_type then got error like Below

```
"status": "failed",
"message": "\"Card number is required\"",
```

Anyone can help me to solve this error it would be very helpful.

Comment: This error occurs when you try to pass raw card details to your Server with new Stripe accounts - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810129/sending-credit-card-numbers-directly-to-the-stripe-api-is-generally-unsafe-to-c I would suggest reaching out to Pabbly, as it doesn't appear you can have control over their payment process.